How to determine the power rating of transformer
How can I determine the power rating of a 3-phase transformer 33/0.415 from a construction point of view?
I understand that kVA = V x I x 1.73 / 1000.
But, if I may ask how can I be able to determine the rated current of the transformer undergoing construction? it is from the number of turns? or the gauge of the coil?

For power transformers, the most common limiting factor for a transformer's power transfer capability is the heat generated by losses in the transformer, and the subsequent rise in temperature of the transformer.
Transformers have power losses due to

Eddy currents in the core
Hysteresis in the core
Resistance in the windings

The core losses depend on the core construction and applied voltage of the transformer and are more or less independent of the secondary current of the transformer.
The winding resistance losses depend upon the gauges of the wires, and the vary approximately proportionally with the secondary current.
These losses generate heat and raise the temperature of the transformer. High temperatures in the transformer have two important effects

Temporary degradation of the magnetic properties of the core
Permanent degradation of the insulation of the wires in the core

To avoid degradation of the transformer's performance, the temperature within the transformer needs to be limited, and hence the power dissipated in the transformer needs to be limited.
A transformer's power transfer capabilities can be improved by increasing the gauge of the wires. However, in power transformers, this is often limited the size of the windows in the core. Increasing the core size can help by increasing the window size. However, increasing the core size often means increasing the core losses as well.
Increasing the thermal conductivity of the transformer is another technique for increasing power transfer capabilities. Thus, overhead distribution transformers are usually in an oil filled can, and many have special heat-sink like fins on the can to assist with heat removal.
All in all, there is a great deal of technical art to designing a transformer capable of handling a given level of power transfer.

But, if I may ask how can I be able to determine the rated current of the transformer undergoing construction? it is from the number of turns? or the gauge of the coil?

Because temperature is often the limiting factor, one cannot determine the power transfer capabilities of a transformer from the number of turns in a winding, or the gauge of the wire. Two transformer with identical numbers of turns, and identical gauges of wire might tolerate different temperatures, or have different thermal resistances to the ambient air.

Great explanation, however, i tend to look at it from a practical point of view.
How can I determine the Power of a transformer i.e 500kva, 1000kva etc.
when look at varing parameters or calculation during construction, or let say, is it the number of turns or gauge that determines Power ratings that the transformers will delivers to load.
2, how can I determine the number of turns for Primary and secondary windings when we have 33,000 / 415 = 79.51

@Kiki-ko The minimum number of turns for a winding in a fixed frequency transformer is fixed by the core and the voltage across that winding.
